# Functions to calculate max windspeed, average winspeed and median

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am totally new to data structure and algorithms. As much as i am learning and trying to pick up the various functions i was asked to display 5 sets of data structure based on a sample data in csv.

Each file contains a year’s worth of data for multiple sensors. Data for each date-time recording are on separate rows. Within each row, the value for each sensor is separated by a comma. There are a total of 105,120 rows per year/file. Currently the client has 10 years of data which is a million records.

I am supposed to find out:

1. The maximum wind speed of a specified month and year.
2. The median wind speed of a specified year.
3. Average wind speed for each month of a specified year. Display the data in the order of month (Jan, Feb, Mar, ...)
4. Total solar radiation for each month of a specified year. Display the data in a descending order of the solar radiation (i.e. month with the highest total solar radiation will display first).
5. Given a date, show the times for the highest solar radiation for that date. There can be one or more time values with the same highest solar radiation. Display the list of times in descending order (e.g. 24:00, 23:00, 22:00, etc.)

As i am new to Data structure. I have been cracking hard on the type of algorithms to propose on the above. 
I am thinking if i can use:

BST Binary Search Tree to solve Qns 1
Linear for Qns 2
Constant to sort and linear to find the average for Qns 3
Both linear for Qns 4 and 5.

Anyone have a better suggestion or sample pseudo code to share on this. Or how should i start.

Regards, Heaptie

Comment: The scenario sounds more like a database use case to me. A database will not provide you with the fastest possible solution (Still all queries should run sub second when using indexes), but it will be more flexible than building custom data structures for each query.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What language/libraries would you be using to solve this? Most languages will have libraries that can solve aggregation of large datasets for you. Like numpy and pandas in python.